# phpMyAdmin: Join three columns, count how many times each value exists, and display the PK that each is referencing

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a number of tables with two being Diagnostics (test_id, test_name) and Evaluation (evaluation_id, test_1, test_2, test_3). Test_1, 2, 3 are foreign keys referencing Diagnostics.test_id. I need to count the number of times each test is administered (across all 3 test columns), only show the ones that have been administered 3 or more times, and give their corresponding test_name.

My current query is:

```
SELECT test, count(*) Total
FROM
(SELECT test_1 AS test FROM Evaluation
 UNION ALL
 SELECT test_2 FROM Evaluation
 UNION ALL
 SELECT test_3 FROM Evaluation) d
GROUP BY test
HAVING COUNT(Total) > 2
ORDER BY test
```

This groups and counts each test across the three columns but doesn't translate the tests into their corresponding test names. I'm relatively new at phpMyAdmin so any help would be great!

Comment: Hope you try to find answer here, It is good time to read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Read it and edit the answer. Then you can get best answers. also look at [this question] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908118/help-needed-in-getting-total-resource-count-sql-server-2005) which is properly describe with sample data.,

Comment: To look up foreign keys, you need to use a join.

Comment: @MandyShaw I know how to look up foreign keys for a single column but not when the three columns are combined and counted.

Comment: What if there's 4th test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT test, test_name, count(*) Total
FROM
(
SELECT test_1 as test, test_name FROM Evaluation e
join Diagnostics di on e.test_1 = di.test_id
UNION ALL
SELECT test_2 as test, test_name FROM Evaluation e
join Diagnostics di on e.test_2 = di.test_id
UNION ALL
SELECT test_3 as test, test_name FROM Evaluation e
join Diagnostics di on e.test_3 = di.test_id
) d
GROUP BY test, test_name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
ORDER BY test [or test_name if preferred]
```

Note that each select in the UNION is completely independent of the others.

Comment: Thanks. Another time I would suggest you don't use the phpmyadmin tag as this is a straight SQL question and you could easily have excluded potential answerers from looking at the question.